# Rolling average by group R data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I want to compute a YTD rolling average by group starting from the first row in the group and ending at the last row. Sample below...

```
Group <- c(rep("a",5), rep("b",5))
Sales <- c(2,4,3,3,5,9,7,8,10,11)
Result <- c(2,3,3,3,3.4,9,8,8,8.5,9)
df <- data.frame(Group, Sales, Result)
```

The Result column is what I am expecting to see from the rolling average.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Using `cumsum`:

```
dt <- as.data.table(df)
dt[, res := cumsum(Sales)/(1:.N), by = Group]
dt
    Group Sales Result res
 1:     a     2    2.0 2.0
 2:     a     4    3.0 3.0
 3:     a     3    3.0 3.0
 4:     a     3    3.0 3.0
 5:     a     5    3.4 3.4
 6:     b     9    9.0 9.0
 7:     b     7    8.0 8.0
 8:     b     8    8.0 8.0
 9:     b    10    8.5 8.5
10:     b    11    9.0 9.0
```

or with `rollapplyr` from the `zoo` package:

```
dt[, res := rollapplyr(Sales, 1:.N, mean), by = Group]
```

or with base R:

```
ave(df$Sales, df$Group, FUN = function(x) cumsum(x) / seq_along(x))
```

Comment: or with `rollapplyr` from the `zoo` package: `dt[, res := rollapplyr(Sales, 1:.N, mean), by = Group]` (but yours' is more elegant imo)

Comment: Or without extra packages: `ave(df$Sales, df$Group, FUN = function(x) cumsum(x) / seq_along(x))`

Comment: @nachti thank you, I've been trying various examples out I found but it was the '1:.N' that I was missing.

Comment: I see. You can also write `seq_len(.N)` instead of `1:.N` (just FYI).

Answer (score 2):

We can use `dplyr` with `zoo`.  The `%>%` connects the lhs with the rhs and it is very easy to understand and execute it.

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)
df %>%
   group_by(Group) %>% 
   mutate(Sales = rollapplyr(Sales, row_number(), mean))  
#    Group Sales Result
#    <fctr> <dbl>  <dbl>
#1       a   2.0    2.0
#2       a   3.0    3.0
#3       a   3.0    3.0
#4       a   3.0    3.0
#5       a   3.4    3.4
#6       b   9.0    9.0
#7       b   8.0    8.0
#8       b   8.0    8.0
#9       b   8.5    8.5
#10      b   9.0    9.0
```

Comment: yes this is very easy to understand. I am going with the above one purely because I use data table more often so it keeps my code consistent.

Comment: @MidnightDataGeek  Sure, data.table would be fast